# Symfony 2 - Custom Form Field Type with multiple parent

Tags: symfony, abstract-type

I would like if you have an idea to [create a custom form field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) with two parents ?

I am trying to create a `select2` form type.
But I would like to use this type for `entity` type and `choice` type.

I know `entity` is child of `choice`.
But `entity` has specific options does not exist in `choice`.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Cant you just use `choice` as a parent and create `DataTransformer` in case you need to work with entities?

Comment: So creating a reusable field in `buildForm()` method.  
I did not think about it.  
Thanks for your suggestion! Even if I think it's can become complicated.  
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-a-reusable-issue-selector-field

Comment: Create your own form type which inherits from choice, then add functionalities of entity by yourself